# Generic PS3 controller Retroarch

Tags: ps3

Please bear with me, I am brand new to Linux and RetroArch.

I have a generic PS3 controller, wireless "AfterGlow" with a USB dongle, that I want to use on RetroArch. In spite of my various attempts RetroArch has failed to detect any inputs from the controller, yes it's on and yes it's fully charged (AA battery powered).
I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. All USB ports are operating. Bluetooth is enabled and functioning properly. Other input devices are all functioning (keyboard, touchscreen, touchpad, wireless mouse with USB dongle).

Comment: It may assist other users to provide a solution if you edit your question to include details of the command or method you are using to run RetroArch and the text of the error message that results.

Comment: No error messages. Just adjusted the input drivers and attempted to map the buttons, never registered the inputs. I feel that they are not getting through or the program is not able to communicate with the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. I forgot to check the permissions... usb and bluetooth access were turned off. Told you I was new to this.

Comment: @abu_bua There is no *other* answer to accept!